# Scala Salat BasicDBObject cannot be cast to

Tags: scala, casbah, salat

I've spent so much time and still don't understand what the problem here.
So I have a collection that data looks like:

```
{ "_id" : "someId", "employment" : { "data" : [ 
    { "retrieved" : { "$date" : "2015-03-12T14:39:41.214Z"} , "value" : { "city" : "someSity" , "fromMonth" : 0 , "name" : "someName" , "fromYear" : 2011 , "toMonth" : 0 , "speciality" : "someSpeciality"}},
    { "retrieved" : { "$date" : "2015-03-12T14:39:41.214Z"} , "value" : { "city" : "someSity" , "fromMonth" : 7 , "name" : "someName" , "fromYear" : 2013 , "toMonth" : 7 , "toYear" : 2014 , "speciality" : "someSpeciality"}},
    { "retrieved" : { "$date" : "2015-03-12T14:39:41.214Z"} , "value" : { "city" : "someSity" , "fromMonth" : 10 , "name" : "someName" , "fromYear" : 2010 , "toMonth" : 10 , "toYear" : 2010 , "speciality" : "someSpeciality"}}
    { "retrieved" : { "$date" : "2015-03-12T14:39:41.214Z"} , "value" : { "fromMonth" : 2 , "name" : "someName" , "fromYear" : 2007 , "toMonth" : 2 , "toYear" : 2010 , "speciality" : "someSpeciality"}}
]}}
```

also I have SalatDAO for that collection:

```
object ProfileDAO extends SalatDAO[Profile, ObjectId](
  collection = MongoFactory.getDB("profiles"))
```

and ofcourse a bunch of `case class`:

```
case class Profile(
  @Key("_id") id: String,
  employment: Option[ListField[Employment]]

case class ListField[T](
  data: List[Value[T]])

case class Value[T](
  value: Option[T],
  retrieved: Option[Instant],
  deleted: Option[Instant])
```

and finally Employment class:

```
case class Employment(
   name: Option[String],
   country: Option[String],
   city: Option[String],
   fromMonth: Option[Int],
   toMonth: Option[Int],
   fromYear: Option[Int],
   toYear: Option[Int],
   speciality: Option[String]
   )
```

Byt when I try do something like this:

```
ProfileDAO.findAll().take(20).map(
    profile => profile.employment.map(
        employment => employment.data.map(
            employmentData => employmentData.value.name)))
.foreach(println)
```

I get Exception: `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com....Employment`
Only one idea I have - some data in DBCollection don't match with Employment class, but there is Option[] evrywhere, so...

Answer (score 0):

Go to where it's blowing up and print the `_id` value of the document that's failing to deserialize?

Comment: for example: 
exception in: Value({ "fromMonth" : 0 , "toMonth" : 0 , "speciality" : "someSpeciality"},Some(Wed Mar 11 18:42:56 MSK 2015),None)

you can see that ProfileDAO deserialize `retrieved: Option[Instant]` and 
  `deleted: Option[Instant]` fields, but not `value: Option[T]` field

Comment: `val employmentColl =  profiles.filter(pr => pr.employment.nonEmpty).map(pr => pr.employment.get)
    val empValues = employmentColl.flatMap(emp => emp.data) //to get rid of ListField[]

    for(value <- empValues){
        try {
          println("city: " + value.value.get("city")) //works, because value here is BasicDBObject
          println("city: " + value.value.city) //throw Exception
        } catch {
          case e: ClassCastException => println("exception in: " + value)
        }
    }`

I tried Employment to extends BasicDBObject - nothing changed

Comment: For me it looks like a bug in Salat

Comment: Can you unwind this nest of types and remove the parameterized classes `Value` and `ListField`?  They don't add very much and they might be obscuring some other bug.  Extending `BasicDBObject` doesn't help anything.  You've got a lot going on here, and your first goal is to get _one_ record to successfully deserialize.  (The way these replies mash your code into unreadable blocks makes it hard to help!)  If `Employment` deserializes successfully after removing `Value` and `ListField`, try adding them back in one by one. If that fails, make a simple GitHub project that demonstrates the error.

Comment: But I need `Value` and `ListField` cause of structure of Data inside, look at original question.

Comment: I read somewhere that this error maybe cause of using scala.List. So I change `ListField` row `data: List[Value[T]]` to `data: java.util.ArrayList[Value[T]]` and what? Now I have the same exception, but on one step above!
`BasicDBObject cannot be cast to com.....Value`

Before that I get exception on casting object inside `Value` (like I wrote in first post). Why this happens? I think I am on the right way

Comment: WOW!
I create new DBCollection and insert one Row with mine ProfileDao, and this is what I get when `db.find()`:

`{ "_id" : "someId", "employment" : { "data" : [ { "value" : [ "Alex", "England", "London" ], "retrieved" : "some time here" }, { "value" : [ "Sasha", "England", "London" ], "retrieved" : "some time here" } ] } }`
So as you can see `Employment` writes as LIST!!! And when I try to deserialize is I get an Exception... Why is this??

Comment: It's serializing as a list because neither Salat nor mongo-java-driver have any idea what to do with it.  If you cannot eliminate those two classes, see if it serializes correctly if you parameterize them.

Comment: Also, could we _please_ take this off SO comments?  Unfortunately the code block formatting is *extremely difficult* to read.  Please create a sample GitHub project demonstrating your error.  We can post back here or edit the original answer when your problem is fixed.